# RewriteRule help directing to and from http/https

Tags: mod-rewrite

In my Apache config file, I have the following to redirect to https if the page name has login in it:

```
<VirtualHost 1.2.3.4:80>
    -- snip --

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^/(.*)login(.*) https://domain/$login$2 [L]
</VirtualHost>
```

And here is the part that I am having troubles with. I want to redirect every page that does not match `^/(.*)login(.*)` back to http.

```
<VirtualHost 1.2.3.4:443>
    -- snip --

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^/(.*) http://domain/$l [L]
</VirtualHost>
```

But as I have it, I created a circular rewrite.

What am I missing?

p.s., the IP 1.2.3.4 is bogus. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solved my issue:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(.*)login(.*)
RewriteRule ^/(.*) http://domain/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Not tested, but should work with:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)login(.*) https://domain/${REQUEST_URI} [L]
RewriteRule (.*[^l][^o][^g][^i][^n].*) http://domain/${REQUEST_URI} [L]
```

Maybe you can also forget the matching of `(.*[^l][^o][^g][^i][^n].*)` qnd replace by `.*` since the `[L]` should stop the HTTPS request from being match after their rewite rule. To be tested.

Comment: This seems to be working in part: `RewriteRule (.*[^l][^o][^g][^i][^n].*) http://domain/${REQUEST_URI} [L]` but it literally redirects to http://domain/${REQUEST_URI}. The actual REQUEST_URI, namely `/admin_console` is not provided in the url.

Comment: I changed it to `http://domain/%{REQUEST_URI}` and that replaces the actual value. However, now I have a redirect loop. :(

Comment: Can you provide an example in your question of : 1. what does the client type, 2. What does the client see as final URI, 3. What are the URL of the actual pages. It would help to refine the rules.